# unable to visulize PointCloud using octomap_mapping

Tags: ros, octomap, ros-kinetic, octomap-mapping, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Turtlebot3 Burger in gazebo simulation. Since it does not have pointcloud2 data, I use laser_geometry package to convert the scan data into pointcloud2. I want to use the octomap_mapping in octomap_server to visualize the pointcloud data. Based on some instructions, I modified the octomap_mapping.launch:

where "pc" is the pointcloud2 converted by laser_geometry.

But when I open rviz and use MarkerArray to visualize the occupied cell, it does show anything. I tried to look at the message in the /occupied_cells_vis_array, and It says no message warning.

Could anyone help me figure out what is going wrong? I am really new to ROS, thanks for patience.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340131/unable-to-visulize-pointcloud-using-octomap_mapping/) by [zhefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50329/zhefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you have a timestamp issue in your publishing of pointcloud2 message from the laser data. octomap_server  integrates pointclouds to the OctoMap only if there's a valid transformation between the frame of the point cloud and the fixed frame specified for octmap_server. So I would double check the timestamps of the generated pointclouds to see if they match with the current ROS time.

---

Originally posted by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) with karma: 246 on 2020-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1